# Epidemic simulation over a large population

Tags: python, performance, simulation

This is a follow-up to my question about [epidemic simulation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/150044/epidemic-simulation). The accepted answer works, but also mentions that I should look at modifying the external_function_call. Here's the complete working code, but it still takes quite a long time to run - in fact, it's slower than what I originally posted.

Here are the first few lines from the profiler, assuming a population size 100 (it's actually 625, which makes the code extremely slow):

```
     11185402 function calls (11184367 primitive calls) in 25.228 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.108    0.108   25.229   25.229 20Dec_for_codereview.py:1(<module>)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.530    0.530 20Dec_for_codereview.py:10(create_pop)
 6585    0.019    0.000    0.019    0.000 20Dec_for_codereview.py:26(checkEqual)
  748   10.670    0.014   16.705    0.022 20Dec_for_codereview.py:29(powerlaw_epidemic)
   58    0.002    0.000    0.013    0.000 20Dec_for_codereview.py:66(inf_per_count_time)
 6321    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 20Dec_for_codereview.py:70(<genexpr>)
    1    0.008    0.008   16.731   16.731 20Dec_for_codereview.py:74(write_powerlaw_epidemics)
```

I'm very sure I'm not using lists as I should, which may be a part of the problem - checkEqual is checking whether all elements in the list are equal to 0.

And here's the code. The purpose of changing the list element to 0 was to keep the spot in the list, but exclude that element from the list of susceptible individuals at time t. I'm also not convinced I should define dist1 as I do, in the loop, but I can't see another way to do it. This code is far too slow, even with the improvements suggested in the epidemic simulation question. How can I make it faster?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy import spatial
import json
import itertools
import collections

MAX_FAILED_ATTEMPS = 10

def create_pop(meanval, sigmaval, pop):
    x_pos, y_pos = np.random.multivariate_normal(meanval, sigmaval, pop).T
    dist_mat = np.asarray(zip(x_pos, y_pos))
    pdistance = scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(dist_mat)
    full_mat = scipy.spatial.distance.squareform(pdistance)

    #Save the population - this happens, but commented out to not save files on someone else's machine
    #with open('20Dec_population.txt', 'w') as f:
    #    xyarray = np.array([x_pos, y_pos])
    #    xyarray = xyarray.T
    #    np.savetxt(f, xyarray, fmt=['%f', '%f'])

    return full_mat


#http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844801/check-if-all-elements-in-a-list-are-identical
def checkEqual(lst):
    return lst[1:] == lst[:-1]

def powerlaw_epidemic(pop, susc, trans, inf_period, eps, full_mat):
    #Purpose:
    #Create a list of susceptible individuals based on the population
    #From the susceptible individuals, choose one to be infectious at time 1
    #Then the susceptible at that position in the list becomes 0
    #And the infectious dictionart gets updated to be {susceptible[chosen_position]:1}
    #While there are still susceptible individuals, allow the epidemic to continue

    susceptible = list(range(1, pop + 1))
    infectious = {}
    t = 1
    while not checkEqual(susceptible): #while there are still susceptible individuals (while susceptible is not all 0s)
        if t == 1:
            inf_1 = int(np.random.randint(1, pop, size=1))
            infectious[inf_1] = t
            inf_times = t
            susceptible[inf_1-1] = 0
        else:
            for ind in susceptible:
                if ind != 0:
                    inf_times = [i for i in infectious.values() if ((t - inf_period <= i and (i < t)))]
                    t_times = set(range(1, t)) #from 1 to t-1
                    infset = set(inf_times)
                    if not t_times.intersection(infset):
                        return infectious
                    l1 = [infectious.values().index(i) for i in inf_times]
                    inf_indivs = [infectious.keys()[i] for i in l1]
                    dist1 = [(full_mat[ind-1, j-1])**(-trans) for j in inf_indivs]
                    probinf = 1 - np.exp(-susc*sum(dist1) + eps)
                    if probinf >= np.random.uniform(0, 1):
                        infectious[ind] = t
                        susceptible[ind-1] = 0
                    else:
                        continue
        t += 1
    return infectious

def inf_per_count_time(infectious):
    inf_count = {}
    c_1 = 0
    for t in range(1, np.max(infectious.values())+1): #to the max time
            inf_count[t] = np.sum(1 for i in infectious.values() if i==t)
    return inf_count #e.g. {2:3} means 3 people became infectious at time 2

#This was the accepted answer from the epidemic simulation question
def write_powerlaw_epidemics(susc, trans, inf_period, eps, repetitions, full_mat):
    epi_list = []
    count_list = []
    new_susc = []
    new_trans = []
    new_inf_period = []
    new_eps = []
    new_count_list = []
    count = 0

    parameters_product = itertools.product(trans, inf_period, eps)
    for transmissibility, infectious_period, epsilon in parameters_product:
        while True:
            for rep in range(repetitions):
                for _ in range(MAX_FAILED_ATTEMPS):
                    g1 = powerlaw_epidemic(
                        pop, susc, transmissibility,
                        infectious_period, epsilon, full_mat)
                if len(g1) >= 10 and max(g1.values()) >= 10:
                    g2 = inf_per_count_time(g1)
                    print 'parameters', transmissibility, infectious_period, epsilon
                    count += 1
                    epi_list.append(g1)
                    count_list.append(g2)
                    new_susc.append(susc)
                    new_trans.append(transmissibility)
                    new_inf_period.append(infectious_period)
                    new_eps.append(epsilon)
                    break #epi was successful, go to next rep
            else:
                transmissibility += 1
                # Cleanup because we failed too many times
                # Note: new_susc[-0:] is not always an empty list, so change if location
                if rep > 0:

                    del epi_list[-rep:]
                    del count_list[-rep:]
                    del new_susc[-rep:]
                    del new_trans[-rep:]
                    del new_inf_period[-rep:]
                    del new_eps[-rep:]

                    count -=1
                break #epi failed, break out of reps and start new para set
        else:
            # do not restart if we made it through the whole repetitions
            print 'wrote', transmissibility, infectious_period, epsilon
            break

    paras =  np.array([
        np.asarray(new_susc),
        np.asarray(new_trans),
        np.asarray(new_inf_period),
        np.asarray(new_eps)
    ]).T
    #This actually happens, but is commented out so no kind person answering this question gets files written to their machine.
    #print 'number of parameter rows', paras[:,0].shape
    #with open('Dec20_powerlaw_parameters.txt', 'w') as newfile1:
    #    np.savetxt(newfile1, paras, fmt = ['%f', '%f', '%f', '%f'])

    print 'final count', count
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pop = 100 
    susc = 0.3
    powerlaw_trans = [1.5, 2.5, 3]
    inf_period = [2, 3]
    eps = [0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.05]
    meanval = np.array([0., 0.])
    sigmaval = np.array([[1., 0.], [0., 1.]])
    full_mat = create_pop(meanval, sigmaval, pop) 
    reps = 2 

    write_powerlaw_epidemics(susc, powerlaw_trans, inf_period, eps, reps, full_mat)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try to implement the advices of the second solution and see if it makes some differences?

Comment: Hi @MathiasEttinger, I tried, but couldn't get it to run, so I accepted the answer I could run.

Comment: Ok. But at least it taught you about `cProfile` ;). We now have real figures to reason about. And as I said, your bottleneck is `power_law_epidemic` as it more than 99% of the running time of `write_powerlaw_epidemics`. Total time of `create_pop` seems also unecessaryly large.

Comment: Yes, you taught me lots of useful stuff! Thanks again. I'm fiddling with power_law_epidemic but it seems storing the matrix outside the loop and just accessing inside the loop is making it worse....Ugh, n00b!

Comment: That last edit looks like it's a comment on the answer. I rolled it back; please avoid editing a question in response to answers. See [help/someone-answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for all the details.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you seem to not use lists as you should. You seems to not use dictionary as you shoud either. In fact, you picked a too complicated data structure for the task at hand.

The aim of your dictionary is to store the date at which people got infected based on the index of the person. The aim of your list is to store a list of uninfected indexes. This is way too contrived as you could associate indexes to a value using just a list (and `enumerate`).

If you use only a single list, storing for each index the date at which the person (for this index) got infected, you can simplify your computation a lot. On top of that, when computing the people infected at time `t`, you include contagious people that were computed in the range \$[t - \text{inf_period}; t[\$, and to do so, you explicitly exclude people contaminated at time `t`. Instead, you could compute the list of infectious people before iterating over `susceptible` to avoid to:

1. Exclude those contaminated at time `t`;
2. Recomputing the same list over and over for each people in the population.

In the following rewrite, I use a list of infection dates, the value 0 meaning the person never got infected yet:

```
def powerlaw_epidemic(pop, susc, trans, inf_period, eps, full_mat):
    """Compute a list of infection date for each people in the population.
    A value of 0 meaning the person never got infected during the simulation.
    """

    infection_dates = np.zeros(pop, dtype=int)
    initial_patient = np.random.randint(1, pop)
    infection_dates[initial_patient] = 1  # First got infected on day 1

    for day in itertools.count(2):
        if infection_dates.all():
            # Stop the simulation if everyone was infected
            return infection_dates

        still_virulent = max(day - inf_period, 1)
        infectious_people = infection_dates >= still_virulent

        if not infectious_people.any():
            # Stop the simulation if noone is infectious anymore
            return infection_dates

        # Compute newly infected persons
        for person, infected_at in enumerate(infection_dates):
            if not infected_at:
                dist = full_mat[person, infectious_people] ** (-trans)
                probinf = 1 - np.exp(-susc * dist.sum() + eps)
                if probinf >= np.random.uniform(0, 1):
                    infection_dates[person] = day
```

A few things to note:

- You don't need to use a test to differentiate the first day from the other ones, just do the special case before the loop to avoid loosing time in a useless test in the loop.
- Since you use `numpy` in various places, you can improve the computation a bit, especially extracting out specific indexes out of `full_mat` or computing the indexes of `infectious_people`.

  You may be able to use `numpy` features to improve the update of `infection_dates` (instead of using a `for` loop), but I don't know `numpy` enough to provide them.

Now you may notice that I return an array where you returned a dictionnary, this means you have to adapt your calling code to handle the change. `inf_per_count_time` is easy to adapt as it only counts the number of people infected on a given day: this calls for [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). But you will also need to adapt your condition to know if a simulation was "virulent enough". Better write a function for that:

```
def is_virulent_enough(simulation, infected=10, duration=10):
    return (simulation > 0).sum() >= infected and simulation.max() >= duration
```

---

`create_pop` could also be simplified as `zip` and `.T` cancel each other; making some re-creation of data superfluous.

---

Using various tips that I already gave in my [previous](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/150056/84718) [answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/150112/84718), you can end up with the following code:

```
import csv
import itertools
import collections
import argparse

import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial


MAX_FAILED_ATTEMPTS = 50
EpidemyStatistics = collections.namedtuple(
    'EpidemyStatistics',
    'susceptibility transmissibility infectious epsilon count infected')


def create_population(pop, meanval=None, sigmaval=None):
    if meanval is None:
        meanval = np.array([0., 0.])
    if sigmaval is None:
        sigmaval = np.array([[1., 0.], [0., 1.]])

    xyarray = np.random.multivariate_normal(meanval, sigmaval, pop)
    pdistance = scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(xyarray)
    full_mat = scipy.spatial.distance.squareform(pdistance)

    with open('20Dec_population.txt', 'w') as f:
        np.savetxt(f, xyarray, fmt=['%f', '%f'])

    return full_mat


def powerlaw_epidemic(pop, susc, trans, inf_period, eps, full_mat):
    """Compute a list of infection date for each people in the population.
    A value of 0 meaning the person never got infected during the simulation.
    """

    infection_dates = np.zeros(pop, dtype=int)
    initial_patient = np.random.randint(1, pop)
    infection_dates[initial_patient] = 1  # First got infected on day 1

    for day in itertools.count(2):
        if infection_dates.all():
            # Stop the simulation if everyone was infected
            return infection_dates

        still_virulent = max(day - inf_period, 1)
        infectious_people = infection_dates >= still_virulent

        if not infectious_people.any():
            # Stop the simulation if noone is infectious anymore
            return infection_dates

        # Compute newly infected persons
        for person, infected_at in enumerate(infection_dates):
            if not infected_at:
                dist = full_mat[person, infectious_people] ** (-trans)
                probinf = 1 - np.exp(-susc * dist.sum() + eps)
                if probinf >= np.random.uniform(0, 1):
                    infection_dates[person] = day


def is_virulent_enough(simulation, infected=10, duration=10):
    return (simulation > 0).sum() >= infected and simulation.max() >= duration


def write_powerlaw_epidemics(population, susc, trans, inf_period, eps, repetitions, full_mat):    
    epidemies = []
    count = 0

    parameters_product = itertools.product(susc, trans, inf_period, eps)
    for susceptibility, transmissibility, infectious_period, epsilon in parameters_product:
        while True:
            for rep in range(repetitions):
                for _ in range(MAX_FAILED_ATTEMPTS):
                    infection_dates = powerlaw_epidemic(
                        population, susceptibility, transmissibility,
                        infectious_period, epsilon, full_mat)

                    if is_virulent_enough(infection_dates):
                        epidemies.append(EpidemyStatistics(
                            susceptibility,
                            transmissibility,
                            infectious_period,
                            epsilon,
                            collections.Counter(infection_dates),
                            infection_dates.tolist()))
                        count += 1
                        break
                else:
                    transmissibility += 1

                    # Cleanup because we failed too many times
                    # Beware of del epidemies[-0:] which delete the whole list
                    if rep:
                        del epidemies[-rep:]
                        count -=1
                    break
            else:
                # do not restart if we made it through the whole repetitions
                break

    print 'number of parameter rows', len(epidemies)
    with open('parameters.txt', 'w') as newfile1:
        writer = csv.writer(newfile1, delimiter=' ')
        writer.writerows(epidemies)

    print count


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Some infos here')
    parser.add_argument('population', type=int)
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--susceptibility', type=float, nargs='+', default=[0.3])
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--transmissibility', type=float, nargs='+', default=[1.5, 2.5, 3])
    parser.add_argument('-i', '--infectious-period', type=int, nargs='+', default=[2, 3])
    parser.add_argument('-e', '--epsilon', type=float, nargs='+', default=[0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.05])
    parser.add_argument('-r', '--repetitions', type=int, default=400)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    full_mat = create_population(args.population)
    write_powerlaw_epidemics(
        args.population,
        args.susceptibility,
        args.transmissibility,
        args.infectious_period,
        args.epsilon,
        args.repetitions,
        full_mat)
```

Comment: Thank you @Mathias Ettinger, but this throws an overflow error:
21Dec_so.py:59: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in power
  dist = full_mat[person, infectious_people] ** (-trans)

Any idea why the error would be thrown now, if it wasn't before? I looked it up, and it means the result is too big to store.

Comment: Cool, never heard of that! [Here you go] (http://pastebin.com/HvsKar9L). A brief description: fullmat is a matrix of distances between individuals. The diagonal is 0, because the distance from a person to themself is 0. I only really need to store the upper (or lower) triangular matrix, but I had trouble getting the positioning of individuals to work in that case. That is, I needed the distance from either individual 1 to individual 2 OR individual 2 to individual 1, and I couldn't get that to work without using the full matrix.

Comment: Ah - the link only has a population of 5 individuals to show the concept.

Comment: @StatsSorceress I got no error running a full 9600 simulations for both 100 (33 seconds) and 625 (4 min 16) population. The only thing I changed was using `duration=2` when checking if the simulation was successful instead of `duration=10` as I saw nobody getting infected past day 6 or 7. So in your case, it must mean the `transmissibility` parameter kept growing and growing until generating the `RuntimeWarning`. I’ll make some further testing comparing your original code and the rewrite as I don't quite understand why, even with large `transmissibility` the number of days doesn't evolve much.

Comment: @StatsSorceress I tried with your original code, the simulations doesn't seem to reach day 10 easily either. You may want to either adjust your formulas, reduce the step of increase of `transmissibility` or reduce your upper bound of required duration.